# How can I prevent ordering by click on column names in datatables?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, click, preventdefault

I want to prevent, that by click on the column names the order changes.

I tried:

```
"ordering": false,
```

This actually removes the click possibility.But then the ordering does not work anymore. I want to keep that, only prevent the user to be able to click on the column names. I tried everything like:

```
$(".sorting").addClass('sorting_disabled').removeClass('sorting');
```

or

```
$(".sorting").click(function(){return false;});
```

or

```
  $( ".sorting" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            $('th.sorting').off();
            $("th.sorting").css('cursor', 'default');
            $("th.sorting_asc").css('cursor', 'default');
            $("th.sorting_desc").css('cursor', 'default');
        }
    } );

    // to show sorting is still possible:
    table.order.listener( '#mysorter', 0 );

} );
```

This removes the sorting events from the table's column headers (the jQuery `off()` function), and ensures the mouse icon does not change to a hand when you roll over the headings.

It leaves the arrows in place, so you can see what sort is in effect.

To show that sorting is still possible, I added a button to the page:

```
<button id="mysorter" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

The `table.order.listener()` causes column index 0 to be sorted asc/desc with each button click.

(If you also want to get rid of the sort arrows, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571455/12567365).)